# How to get resultset from call function with @Query in Spring Boot? postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'll try to call function on PostgreSQL with spring repository. In this case, I'm using annotation @Query. When I run the program response is

```
2019-08-15 13:16:14.678  INFO 3160 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] c.r.controllers.MCurrencyController      : currency Id : 2
Hibernate: select * from get_curr(2)
2019-08-15 13:16:14.749  WARN 3160 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2019-08-15 13:16:14.749 ERROR 3160 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name currency_id was not found in this ResultSet
```

The question is how to get the result? Because with @Query can't use @Results.

Before I try the complex procedure. I would use a simple procedure.

```
public interface MCurrencyRepository extends JpaRepository<MCurrency, Integer> {
    List<MCurrency> findByCurrFlag( final String currFlag);
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from get_curr(2)")
    List<MCurrency> currencyList(@Param("currId") int currId);
```

MCurrency.class

```
public class MCurrency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "m_currency_currency_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "currency_id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    private int currId;

    @Column(name = "currency_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Cuurency Name can not be empty")
    private String currName;

    @Column(name = "currency_alias")
    @NotNull(message = "Currency Alias can not be empty")
    private String currAlias;

    @Column(name = "currency_activeyn")
    @NotNull(message = "Currency Flag can not be empty")
    private String currFlag;

    @Column(name = "currency_userid")
    @NotNull(message = "Currency User id can not be empty")
    private int currUserId;

    @Column(name = "currency_lastupdate")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime currLastUpdate;
```

I hope the result is currencyId, currencyName.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the code of your function.

Comment: what is MCurrency? And how does the table look like?

Comment: You have several problems, first being you do not inject the provided curId argument into your native query, this is not causing the problem. Second is that the resulting dataset from `get_cur(2)` does not contain a column named `currency_id`.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius how to define result set for response this function?

Comment: I think you are mixing up MyBatis `Result` with spring support of `Query`. They do not work together and Spring does not allow access to the raw resultset using their automated implementation of `Repository` interfaces.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius i'm not usind MyBatis xml. i just use annotations. :(